# Numbers too big for variables

Tags: java, biginteger

I am to find the last ten digits of 1^1 + 2^2 + 3^3.. + 1000^1000.
Is there any way to find this out with pure logic? I think you can't store a number that big.

This question is from a math competition, but I thought of trying to do this in Java.

Comment: Have a look at BigIntegers, they are big enough to store such numbers.

Comment: You don't need to let the numbers get that big at all. Observe that the higher digits (off towards the left) never affect the lower digits (the ones you want).

Comment: well I haven't really tried anything yet.

Comment: Yeah, I want to find the logic of this. This was a math competition question, so obviously kids gotta do it with pen and paper (some logic)

Comment: Try http://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Least significant 10 digits? For that you would only need number modulo 10^10. A `long` would do; `int`just not.

Comment: Presumably you are using the XOR operator to stand in for exponentation.  If not then the answer is 0.

Comment: @demostene: "This question is from a math competition, but I thought of trying to do this in Java."

Comment: @BoltClock It is easier to do it in java if you know the algorithm first ;)

Comment: In "70F1", you can say the digit[2] (F) has the value of 240, because it's 2nd right to left, hence the real value of a digit is `n*sizeOfBase^pos` being n the unit-value of the digit, sizeOfBase 10 in this case and pos its position 0-indexed right to left. The final number is the sum of relative values of each digit. Now, take these logics and make sizeOfBase = Integer.MAX_VALUE, use an array of ints to represent the digits, and voila. You reinvented the `java.math.BigInteger`, in a possibly clumsy manner, but still.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to store number that big, you just need the last ten digits.  You can store this in a long.

An efficient way to calculate large powers is to multiply and the squares e.g. 19^19 = 19 * 19^2 * 19 ^ 16 = 19 * 19 ^ 2 * 19^2^2^2^2.  When you have value which is greater than 10^10 you can truncate the last 10 digits.

BTW the last ten digits of 1000^1000 is 0000000000 and when your add this to your sum, it's the same as adding zero ;)

---

Edit: While you don't have to use BigInteger, it is simpler to write.

```
BigInteger tenDigits = BigInteger.valueOf(10).pow(10);
BigInteger sum = BigInteger.ZERO;
for (int i= 1; i <= 1000; i++) {
    BigInteger bi = BigInteger.valueOf(i);
    sum = sum.add(bi.modPow(bi, tenDigits));
}
sum = sum.mod(tenDigits);
```

`modPow` is more efficient than `pow` with `mod` seperately as it doesn't have to calculate very large numbers, only the result of the `mod`.

Comment: btw 999^999 last digits are not ...0000000

Comment: BTW the last ten digits of  1^1 + 2^2 + 3^3.. + 1000^1000 is not 0000000000. Because the value of  1^1 + 2^2 + 3^3.. + 1000^1000 is only 333833500 which is a 9 digit number

Comment: @TheGuest interesting, but I don't see how this relates to my answer.

Comment: @PeterLawrey I made a mistake. I thought the question is about sum of the SQUARES of first n natural numbers. My comment is not valid. Thanks for pointing it out

Answer (score 2):

You could use BigIntegers...

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    BigInteger acc = BigInteger.ZERO;

    for (int k = 1; k <= 1000; k++) {
        BigInteger pow = BigInteger.valueOf(k).pow(k);
        acc = acc.add(pow);
    }

    System.out.println(acc);
}
```

Comment: As stated above, if this is for a math puzzle, I don't think just writing out the answer is what they are looking for...

Comment: Another note - If "k" had to go up to a million, it will takes ages for this to run!

Answer (score 1):

I believe the problem comes from Project Euler, so it's not just a math problem; it should require some computation as well. I don't know how it could be solved with pencil and paper other than by duplicating the calculations a computer might make. I can't see much in the way of a purely mathematical solution. Mathematics can help us optimize the code, however.

To raise a^n, find the binary expansion of n:

```
n = n_k x 2^k + n_(k-1) x 2^(k-1) + ... + n_0 x 2^0
```

where `n_i = 0 or 1` are the binary digits of `n` with the zeroth digit on the right. Then

```
a^n = a^(n_k x 2^k) x a^(n_(k-1) x 2^(k-1)) x ... x a^(n_0 x 2^0).
```

We can ignore any factors where `n_i = 0`, since the factor is then `a^0 = 1`. The process can be written as an algorithm which is `O(log n)` time and `O(1)` space (see below).

Next, as a challenge, in order to avoid the use of `BigInteger`, we can break the calculation into two parts: finding the answer `mod 2^10` and finding the answer `mod 5^10`. In both cases the numbers in the relevant ranges and products of numbers in the relevant ranges fit into `long`s. The downside is that we have to use the Chinese Remainder Theorem to recombine the results, but it's not that hard, and it's instructive. The hardest part of using the Chinese Remainder Theorem is finding inverses `mod m`, but that can be accomplished in a straightforward manner using a modification of the Euclidean algorithm.

Asymptotic running time is `O(n log n)`, space is `O(1)`, and everything fits into a few `long` variables, no BigInteger or other sophisticated library required.

```
public class SeriesMod1010 {

  public static long pow(long a,long n,long m) { // a^n mod m
    long result = 1;
    long a2i = a%m; // a^2^i for i = 0, ...
    while (n>0) {
      if (n%2 == 1) {
    result *= a2i;
    result %= m;
      }
      a2i *= a2i;
      a2i %= m;
      n /= 2;
    }
    return result;
  }

  public static long inverse(long a, long m) { // mult. inverse of a mod m
    long r = m;
    long nr = a;
    long t = 0;
    long nt = 1;
    long tmp;
    while (nr != 0) {
      long q = r/nr;
      tmp = nt; nt = t - q*nt; t = tmp;
      tmp = nr; nr = r - q*nr; r = tmp;
    }
    if (r > 1) return -1; // no inverse
    if (t < 0) t += m;
    return t;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    long twoTo10 = 1024;
    long sum210 = 0;
    for (long i=1; i<=1000; i++) {
      sum210 += pow(i,i,twoTo10);
      sum210 %= twoTo10;
    }

    long fiveTo10 = 9_765_625;
    long sum510 = 0;
    for (long i=1; i<=1000; i++) {
      sum510 += pow(i,i,fiveTo10);
      sum510 %= fiveTo10;
    }

    // recombine the numbers with the Chinese remainder theorem
    long tenTo10 = 10_000_000_000L;
    long answer = sum210 * inverse(fiveTo10,twoTo10) * fiveTo10
      + sum510 * inverse(twoTo10,fiveTo10) * twoTo10;
    answer %= tenTo10;
    System.out.println(answer);
  }

}
```

Comment: this seems like a good algorithm. What is n_i suppose to mean? just a way to show n * i?

Comment: n_i is the ith binary digit of n, with zeroth digit at right end.

Answer (score 0):

It can be solved without `BigInteger`, because you need to store only 10 last digits on every addition or multiplication operation, using `%` to avoid overflow:

```
int n = 1000;
long result = 0;
long tenDigits = 10_000_000_000L;
for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    long r = i;
    for (int j = 2; j <= i; j++) {
        r = (r * i) % tenDigits;
    }
    result += r;
}  
return result % tenDigits;
```

Complexity is O(N^2), supposed that multiplication runs in constant time.

Answer: 9110846700.

Comment: This will keep squaring `r` rather than calculating r ^ n.  Also 9,999,999,999 ^ 2 will overflow.

Comment: @PeterLawrey corrected: r = (r * i) instead of r = (r * r)

Comment: Long.MAX_VALUE is 9,223,372,036,854,775,807 is total of 19 digits but not all possible values for 19 digits so only 18 digits is safe.

Comment: I suspect using `modPow` is more efficient if you use BigInteger instead. ;)

Comment: You're right about long overflow in your comment, but it can never happen in my code because I don't take squares there. After each multiplication result is truncated.

Comment: Correct, the largest result of `r * i` is limited to 3 + 10 = 13 digits.

Answer (score 0):

use BigIntegers :

```
    import java.math.BigInteger;

public class Program {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BigInteger result = new BigInteger("1");
        BigInteger temp = new BigInteger("1");
        BigInteger I;
        for(int i = 1 ; i < 1001 ; i++){
            I = new BigInteger(""+i);
            for(int j = 1 ; j < i ; j++){
                temp = temp.multiply(I);
            }
            result = result.multiply(temp);
            temp = new BigInteger("1");
        }
        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The decimal base uses 0...9 (10 digits) to represent digits, a number that is in the second position right to left represents Digits * base.length^l2rPosition. Using this logics you can create a class that "pretty much does what your primary school teacher told you to, back when we used paper to calculate stuff, but with a baseN number and base-to-base conversions" I have done this class fully functional in C#, but I don't have time to translate it completely to java, this is about the same logics behind java.math.BigInteger. (with less performance I bet for I used a lot of lists >_>" No time to optimize it now

```
class IntEx {
    ArrayList<Integer> digits = new ArrayList<>();
    long baseSize = Integer.MAX_VALUE+1;
    boolean negative = false;

    public IntEx(int init)
    {
        set(init);
    }

    public void set(int number)
    {
        digits = new ArrayList<>();
        int backup = number;
        do
        {
            int index = (int)(backup % baseSize);
            digits.add(index);
            backup = (int) (backup / baseSize);
        } while ((backup) > 0);
    }

    // ... other operations
    private void add(IntEx number)
    {
        IntEx greater = number.digits.size() > digits.size() ? number : this;
        IntEx lesser = number.digits.size() < digits.size() ? number : this;
        int leftOvers = 0;
        ArrayList<Integer> result = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < greater.digits.size() || leftOvers > 0; i++)
        {
            int sum;
            if (i >= greater.digits.size())
                sum = leftOvers;
            else if(i >= lesser.digits.size())
                sum = leftOvers + greater.digits.get(i);
            else
                sum = digits.get(i) + number.digits.get(i) + leftOvers;
            leftOvers = 0;
            if (sum > baseSize-1)
            {
                while (sum > baseSize-1)
                {
                    sum -= baseSize;
                    leftOvers += 1;
                }
                result.add(sum);
            }
            else
            {
                result.add(sum);
                leftOvers = 0;
            }
        }
        digits = result;
    }
    private void multiply(IntEx target)
    {
        ArrayList<IntEx> MultiParts = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < digits.size(); i++)
        {
            IntEx thisPart = new IntEx(0);
            thisPart.digits = new ArrayList<>();
            for (int k = 0; k < i; k++)
                thisPart.digits.add(0);
            int Leftovers = 0;
            for (int j = 0; j < target.digits.size(); j++)
            {
                int multiFragment = digits.get(i) * (int) target.digits.get(j) + Leftovers;
                Leftovers = (int) (multiFragment / baseSize);
                thisPart.digits.add((int)(multiFragment % baseSize));
            }
            while (Leftovers > 0)
            {
                thisPart.digits.add((int)(Leftovers % baseSize));
                Leftovers = (int) (Leftovers / baseSize);
            }
            MultiParts.add(thisPart);
        }
        IntEx newNumber = new IntEx(0);
        for (int i = 0; i < MultiParts.size(); i++)
        {
            newNumber.add(MultiParts.get(i));
        }
        digits = newNumber.digits;
    }

    public long longValue() throws Exception
    {
        int position = 0;
        long multi = 1;
        long retValue = 0;
        if (digits.isEmpty()) return 0;
        if (digits.size() > 16) throw new Exception("The number within IntEx class is too big to fit into a long");
        do
        {
            retValue += digits.get(position) * multi;
            multi *= baseSize;
            position++;
        } while (position < digits.size());
        return retValue;
    }

    public static long BaseConvert(String number, String base)
    {
        boolean negative = number.startsWith("-");
        number = number.replace("-", "");
        ArrayList<Character> localDigits = new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i = number.toCharArray().length - 1; i >=0; i--) {
            localDigits.add(number.charAt(i));
        }
        // List<>().reverse is missing in this damn java. -_-
        long retValue = 0;
        long Multi = 1;
        char[] CharsBase = base.toCharArray();
        for (int i = 0; i < number.length(); i++)
        {
            int t = base.indexOf(localDigits.get(i));
            retValue += base.indexOf(localDigits.get(i)) * Multi;
            Multi *= base.length();
        }
        if (negative)
            retValue = -retValue;
        return retValue;
    }

    public static String BaseMult(String a, String b, String Base)
    {
        ArrayList<String> MultiParts = new ArrayList<>();
        // this huge block is a tribute to java not having "Reverse()" method.
        char[] x = new char[a.length()];
        char[] y = new char[b.length()];
        for(int i = 0; i < a.length(); i++) {
            x[i] = a.charAt(a.length()-i);
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < b.length(); i++) {
            y[i] = a.charAt(a.length()-i);
        }
        a = new String(x);
        b = new String(y);
        // ---------------------------------------------------------------------
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length(); i++)
        {
            ArrayList<Character> thisPart = new ArrayList<>();
            for (int k = 0; k < i; k++)
                thisPart.add(Base.charAt(0));
            int leftOvers = 0;
            for (int j = 0; j < b.length(); j++)
            {
                // Need I say repeated characters in base may cause mayhem?
                int MultiFragment = Base.indexOf(a.charAt(i)) * Base.indexOf(b.charAt(j)) + leftOvers;
                leftOvers = MultiFragment / Base.length();
                thisPart.add(Base.charAt(MultiFragment % Base.length()));
            }
            while (leftOvers > 0)
            {
                thisPart.add(Base.charAt(leftOvers % Base.length()));
                leftOvers = leftOvers / Base.length();
            }
            char[] thisPartReverse = new char[thisPart.size()];
            for(int z = 0; z < thisPart.size();z++)
                thisPartReverse[z] = thisPart.get(thisPart.size()-z);
            MultiParts.add(new String(thisPartReverse));
        }
        String retValue = ""+Base.charAt(0);
        for (int i = 0; i < MultiParts.size(); i++)
        {
            retValue = BaseSum(retValue, MultiParts.get(i), Base);
        }
        return retValue;
    }

    public static String BaseSum(String a, String b, String Base)
    {
        // this huge block is a tribute to java not having "Reverse()" method.
        char[] x = new char[a.length()];
        char[] y = new char[b.length()];
        for(int i = 0; i < a.length(); i++) {
            x[i] = a.charAt(a.length()-i);
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < b.length(); i++) {
            y[i] = a.charAt(a.length()-i);
        }
        a = new String(x);
        b = new String(y);
        // ---------------------------------------------------------------------
        String greater = a.length() > b.length() ? a : b;
        String lesser = a.length() < b.length() ? a : b;
        int leftOvers = 0;
        ArrayList<Character> result = new ArrayList();
        for (int i = 0; i < greater.length() || leftOvers > 0; i++)
        {
            int sum;
            if (i >= greater.length())
                sum = leftOvers;
            else if (i >= lesser.length())
                sum = leftOvers + Base.indexOf(greater.charAt(i));
            else
                sum = Base.indexOf(a.charAt(i)) + Base.indexOf(b.charAt(i)) + leftOvers;
            leftOvers = 0;
            if (sum > Base.length()-1)
            {
                while (sum > Base.length()-1)
                {
                    sum -= Base.length();
                    leftOvers += 1;
                }
                result.add(Base.charAt(sum));
            }
            else
            {
                result.add(Base.charAt(sum));
                leftOvers = 0;
            }
        }
        char[] reverseResult = new char[result.size()];
        for(int i = 0; i < result.size(); i++)
            reverseResult[i] = result.get(result.size() -i);
        return new String(reverseResult);
    }

    public static String BaseConvertItoA(long number, String base)
    {
        ArrayList<Character> retValue = new ArrayList<>();
        boolean negative = false;
        long backup = number;
        if (negative = (backup < 0))
            backup = -backup;
        do
        {
            int index = (int)(backup % base.length());
            retValue.add(base.charAt(index));
            backup = backup / base.length();
        } while ((backup) > 0);
        if (negative)
            retValue.add('-');
        char[] reverseRetVal = new char[retValue.size()];
        for(int i = 0; i < retValue.size(); i++)
            reverseRetVal[i] = retValue.get(retValue.size()-i);
        return new String(reverseRetVal);
    }

    public String ToString(String base)
    {
        if(base == null || base.length() < 2)
            base = "0123456789";
        ArrayList<Character> retVal = new ArrayList<>();
        char[] CharsBase = base.toCharArray();
        int TamanhoBase = base.length();
        String result = ""+base.charAt(0);
        String multi = ""+base.charAt(1);
        String lbase = IntEx.BaseConvertItoA(baseSize, base);
        for (int i = 0; i < digits.size(); i++)
        {
            String ThisByte = IntEx.BaseConvertItoA(digits.get(i), base);
            String Next = IntEx.BaseMult(ThisByte, multi, base);
            result = IntEx.BaseSum(result, Next, base);
            multi = IntEx.BaseMult(multi, lbase, base);
        }
        return result;
    }

    public static void main(String... args) {
        int ref = 0;
        IntEx result = new IntEx(0);
        while(++ref <= 1000)
        {
            IntEx mul = new IntEx(1000);
            for (int i = 0; i < 1000; ++i) {
                mul.multiply(new IntEx(i));
            }
            result.add(mul);
        }
        System.out.println(result.toString());
    }
}
```

Disclaimer: This is a rough translation/localization from a C# study, there are lots of code omitted. This is "almost" the same logics behind java.math.BigInteger (you can open BigInteger code on your favorite designer and check for yourself. If may I be forgetting a overloaded operator behind not translated to java, have a bit of patience and forgiveness, this example is just for a "maybe" clarification of the theory.

Also, just a sidenote, I know it is "Trying to reinvent the wheel", but considering this question has academic purpose I think its fairly rasonable to share.
One can see the result of this study on [gitHub](https://github.com/figloalds/IntExProject) (not localized though), I'm not expanding that C# code here for its very extensive and not the language of this question.

Answer (score 0):

This gives the correct answer without excess calculations. A Long is sufficient.

```
public String lastTen() {
        long answer = 0;
        String txtAnswer = "";
        int length = 0;
        int i = 1;

        for(i = 1; i <= 1000; i++) {
            answer += Math.pow(i, i);
            txtAnswer = Long.toString(answer);
            length = txtAnswer.length();
            if(length > 9) break;
        }
        return txtAnswer.substring(length-10);
    }
```